# How to configure antisamy in cq 5.5?

Tags: xss, aem, owasp, antisamy

I have cq 5.5 project.

I want to Prevent XSS attacks.

According this [link](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/security_checklist.html#Protect%20against%20Cross-Site%20Scripting%20%28XSS%29) cq provides integration with AntiSamy project.

Please provide concrete steps for integration with AntiSamy because I really cannot find it.

### update

Should I write code like this somewhere?

```
import org.owasp.validator.html.*;

Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(POLICY_FILE_LOCATION);

AntiSamy as = new AntiSamy();
CleanResults cr = as.scan(dirtyInput, policy);

MyUserDAO.storeUserProfile(cr.getCleanHTML()); // some custom function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XSS protection mechanism offered by CQ is already based on the AntiSamy Project. You only need to provide your custom antisamy configuration, in case the default configuration doesn't suit your needs.

The default antisamy configuration is present at `/libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml`, which can be overlaid with your custom config within `/apps`.

You can make use of the XSS Protection API available in CQ, to protect your website from security attacks. The [XSSAPI](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/xss/XSSAPI.html) and the [XSSFilter](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/xss/XSSFilter.html#filter(com.adobe.granite.xss.ProtectionContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) classes provide various methods to validate the given values.

The `xssAPI` is available as an implicit object on inclusion of `/libs/foundation/global.jsp`, whereas the XSSFilter can be obtained and used as shown below.

```
XSSFilter xssFilter = sling.getService(XSSFilter.class);
String filteredString = xssFilter.filter(ProtectionContext.HTML_HTML_CONTENT,
                            dirtyInput, POLICY_FILE_LOCATION);
```

You can find some predefined policy files and steps to create a new configuration [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project#tab=How_do_I_get_started_3F).

**UPDATE:**

In case you do not want to use the XSS API, then you need to have the owasp esapi bundle installed in your instance, and then you can use the code mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok. I will write config.xml. Does  **XSS Protection API**  unrelated thing ?

Comment: I am sorry, i couldn't get you. What does "Does XSS Protection API unrelated thing" mean?

Comment: Can I use **AntiSamy** without **XSS Protection API**?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it is advisable to use the XSSAPI

Comment: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/security_checklist.html looks like in cq5 I cannot use antysamy

Comment: how to check whether antysamy uses ?

Comment: Like i mentioned, antisamy classes are not exposed in CQ5. You need to install them separately in your instance.

Comment: Can you provide steps for install it in my instance?

Comment: I noticed that [link](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/security_checklist.html) here (link mentioned in question but for another version of cq - 5.5 vs 5.6) doesn't contain anything about antySamy. Why?

Comment: Locally I have cq 5.5 and cq 5.6 and nowhere I see bundle owasp esapi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57546/discussion-between-rakhi4110-and-gstackoverflow).