# How to install owasp esapi bundle for antisami library in cq 5.5(and 5.6)?

Tags: integration, xss, aem, osgi-bundle, antisamy

I asked [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800295/how-to-configure-antysamy-in-cq-5-5/24801677) about integration antysami library and cq. But I have related questions to result achieve.

I noticed that [cq5 documentation for 5.5](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/security_checklist.html#Protect%20against%20Cross-Site%20Scripting%20%28XSS%29) doesn't contain information about antisamy(on the other hand [cq 5.6 documentaion](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/security_checklist.html#Protect%20against%20Cross-Site%20Scripting%20%28XSS%29) contains this information)

In [answer to question I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24801677/2674303) I see that for using antysamy I should  have installed owasp esapi bundle installed in your instance. Now I have two instances of cq locally (5.5 and 5.6.1 versions). In both instances I see

> /libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml

But both instances don't contain owasp esapi bundle. (I watch it by this link: `http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles`)

Please provide steps for achieve owasp esapi bundle installation to my local instance. Does this procedure differ for cq 5.5 and cq 5.6(.1) ?

### UPDATE:

my current meaning(please approve or correct it) looks so:

1. download from
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.esapi/2.0GA_1
   third party bundle and install it to cq.

   After this step I saw that this bundle in state installed(not
   active)
2. To make mentioned bundle active I installed this bundle list to my
       instances:

   ```
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antisamy/1.4.5_1
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-beanutils/1.8.3_2
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-configuration/1.4_4
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces/2.11.0_1
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver/1.2_1
   ```

please correct if I wrong.

Comment: why do you have this opinion?

Comment: Correct me if I'am wrong, but you are just asking how to install / configure a tool. Even if the tool itself is a programming tool. The question about how to install it, is a software related question and so it is Off-Topic on SO.

Comment: Here a lot of questions about "where should I click for achieve....in Eclipse"

Comment: Yeah, but thats why this is close to the edge or even as in my eyes, over the edge of off-topic. But nvm.